# Create separate models/tables that are subset of base model

Tags: python, django

I have a Transaction model that contains the list of all transactions from my bank account. I want to create "sub" models that are just different categories of transactions. For instance, an Income model that just contains the deposits or a Bill model that contains the transactions that are from bills. The closest I could find were proxy models but either they are too complex for me to understand or I'm totally wrong anyway.

```
class Transaction(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.description + ' ' + str(self.amount)

class Income(Transaction):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Depends on what do you want to achieve by this. Should those sub-models have their own specific attributes? Is `Transaction` abstract only?

Comment: No, they have exactly the same attributes

Comment: In that case I'd suggest adding a `category` field with [choices](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#choices) (if they are static) instead of inheritance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `category` field with [choices](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#choices) instead of inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from what @rakyi said if we need to do model operation based on that then there is another possible way to use `django-polymorphic`[link](https://django-polymorphic.readthedocs.io/en/stable/). This also support `DRF` so it's very powerful and useful.